# Rails where not exists

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Is there any short way to write this?

```
Person.where.not(age: 10).exists?
```

I am not sure how to write Person.exists?(age is not 10)
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use "raw" SQL to act as the ActiveRecord `where.not`:

```
Person.exists?(['age != ?', 10])
```